# Multiplicity of each eigenvalue in a minimal polynomial of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, jordan-normal-form, minimal-polynomials

It is well known that for a $n \times n$ matrix $A$ ,
the charicteristic polynomial  $p(x)$ satisfies

$p(x)=\prod_{\lambda : eigenvector}  (x-\lambda)^{a(\lambda)}$

where $a(\lambda )$ is the algebraic multiplicity of $\lambda$

The minimal polynomial of $A$ , $\mu _A (x) $  can also be represented as a form of

$\mu_A (x)=\prod (x-\lambda)^{b(\lambda)}$

The question is: if the geometric multiplicity of $\lambda$ is  $g( \lambda )$, is

$b(\lambda ) \le a(\lambda )-g(\lambda )+1$ ?

I think I saw this inequality somewhere, but I'm failing to find how to prove it, and I'm not even sure if it works. Please tell me whether it works, and a proof if it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is true.  Suppose that the Jordan normal form of $A$ has Jordan blocks with eigenvalue $\lambda$ of sizes $k_1,\dots,k_m$.  Then $$a(\lambda)=\sum_{i=1}^mk_i,$$ $$g(\lambda)=m,$$ and $$b(\lambda)=\max(k_1,\dots,k_m).$$  Thus $$a(\lambda)-g(\lambda)=\sum_{i=1}^m(k_i-1)\geq b(\lambda)-1$$ since $b(\lambda)$ is one of the $k_i$.  (This is assuming $\lambda$ actually is an eigenvalue at all; if not then $a(\lambda)=g(\lambda)=b(\lambda)=0$ and the inequality still holds.)